# UK Open Retail Locations Data

Tags: geospatial

[We](https://geolytix.net) just released an open dataset for UK retail locations. We are working on getting this into Open Street Map in the future but for now we will release GIS files and tables. There is some more information on our blog. Feel free to use and share the data.

http://blog.geolytix.net/2016/10/19/retail-points-update/

Comment: not a question, so i had to vote to close, sorry. but do get that into osm, and feel free to share r/datasets, and in data.world, as well as adding that data to the open data se datahub.io portal.

Comment: i didn't know about datahu.io. thanks for the information. we will create an organization there.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a question